# Do int8_t, int16_t, int32_t and int64_t have same respective ranges on different C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, range

Or this is dependent on the 16 bit, 32 bit, etc. compiler?

Also, are these data types valid in C, C# or Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intN_t` is a exact-width integer type of `N` bits long. Per the C11 draft N1570 7.2.1.1 they are defined as:

> The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

However

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

These types are valid in C and C++.  The reason we have these as normal `short`, `int`, and `long long` have no guarantees on their size except for a minimum range

In C# this would be equivalent to the `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64` types.  In Java we can use `byte`, `short`, `int` and `long` as those are all [guaranteed to be of an exact width.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Can you cite the source of your quotes?  (which C99-esque draft, or is it from the real one?)  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf appears to be a draft of some kind with similar (exactly the same?) wording in it.

Comment: @Yakk I added my source.  I completely missed that part.  Sorry.

Comment: @NathanOliver The question was tagged `C++`. Is it correct to say that these types are standardized in C++? They are not mentioned in [\ [basic.fundamental\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental). As a matter of fact the C++ standard mentions them incidentally only in [\[cstdint.syn\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint.syn).

Comment: @Belloc Yes, they are standardized.  It's just that C++ falls back to the C standard here per [\[cstdint.syn\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint.syn#2)

Answer (score 5):

The C++ Standard requires that `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, and `int64_t` be exactly the specified width, with unsigned counterparts prefixed with `u`, *only if such types exist on the target platform*. And yes, these are valid, standard types in C. Java and C# contain no such integral data types of the same names.

Related types are `intN_least_t` and `intN_fast_t`, where the "least" types have at least the number of bits specified.

Answer (score 0):

They have same range based on std C++. More details [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)

and They are valid on C, but not sure on Java and C#

Comment: This answer implies that the C++ standard mandates that every compiler support `int main() { int64_t x; }` as a valid program.  It does not.  Could you clarify?

Comment: They are available in `stdint.h`. Did you included the header

Comment: The C++ standard *does not mandate* that they are in `stdint.h`.  It says the may be there, and if they are they must have certain properties.  What happens to be in your `stdint.h` (or mine) doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf -- this is a link to the working draft standard for C++.  In it, it states that those types do not have to be in `stdint.h`.  I have repeated myself 3 times now, I am done.  The other two answers describe it in easier to understand terms, as does http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Can you specify the line, where you encounter that it does not have to be in `stdint.h` as this come from `c99` to C++. They refer it as `cstdint`. Are we in same page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102259/discussion-between-deleisha-and-yakk).

Comment: 18.4.1 [cstdint.syn] `typedef
signed integer type
int8_t;
// optional
typedef
signed integer type
int16_t;
// optional
typedef
signed integer type
int32_t;
// optional
typedef
signed integer type
int64_t;
// optional` -- while the comments are not normative, they are pretty clear that these are *optional*.  here is a draft of the C standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf [7.18.1.1/3] "These types are optional."

Comment: Please see `section 7.1.2` of the link you have provided

Comment: That is a list of standard headers.  It does not state what they contain.  Section 7.18 describes the `<stdint.h>` header file in C, and it states those types are optional in 7.18.1.1/3.  **The contents of a given header file on a particular system are not evidence of what the C or C++ standard defines**.  They are *optional*, of course they could be on your system.  If you are confused further, please post a question on stack overflow on the subject.